# Password manager/generator with specifics

Tags: passwords, password-management, nokia-e-series, password-generation

I'm looking for a password manager/generator that will work with Google Chrome, my Nokia E72 (S60 3rd Edition, Feature Pack 2) and be easily accessible when working on another computer (e.g. a public computer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately I found no software to do what I wanted specifically.  That being said, Molly's answer comes as close as it gets.

Answer (score 6):

**[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)** is an **online password manager** and form filler that makes web browsing easier and more secure.

- Use LastPass to **generate secure random passwords** to protect your online identity.
- Using a Mac, Windows, or Linux? LastPass **works everywhere**.
- Automatically synchronizes your data: access it from **anywhere at anytime**.

As for your Nokia E72, LastPass for Symbian S60 is available [here](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php).

Comment: whilst this is a great recommendation, the software for the E72 isn't great.

Answer (score 5):

[Keepass](http://www.keepass.info/) have a portable version, and is ported for mobiles (and many other devices): [keepassj2me](http://keepassj2me.sourceforge.net/) for S60. And you could keep your database on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for easy access

Comment: While i personally like KeePass better (i don't believe in the cloud :), using your USB stick is not always an option with public terminals.

Comment: I was using passwordsafe and gorilla on Linux, but I moved to Keepass. I find it easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Clipperz (http://www.clipperz.com/) is a good online solution for password management. Their system not only allows for you to store the username and password, but also other information relating to the system the password is used for (e.g. the support phone number for an online store). They also have an offline read only version, so that you can use still access your database even if you do not have an internet connection, or if you do not want the inherit latency of the internet.

I am not sure if it generates a password for you automatically. If not I would recommend GoodPassword by Bytes Interactive (http://www.goodpassword.com).